# Live attributes in SmartTarget/Fredhopper

Tags: 2011, smarttarget, fredhopper

Reading the [online docs (login required)](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP2&lang=en-US#docid=task_82856AA86458420E9DAF820F7EC83FA1&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=SystemManager_Navigation_Index.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_82856AA86458420E9DAF820F7EC83FA1&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP2&lang=en-US&action=search&query=reindex&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1396609136921&currentQuery=reindex&currentScope=) on **Adding attributes to the navigation index** attributes are *made live* by clicking the red dot next to an attribute name - you then need to perform a full re-index.

If an attribute is *not* live then does this mean using it as part of location query (below, componentid is not live) will just not return any results?

```
fh_location=//catalog01/en_US/publicationid=tcm_0_72_1/componentid=tcm_72_55653_16
```

Having discovered that componentid is not live in our system and I need to query by it I don't really want to reindex over 6000 pieces of XML just to make this attribute queryable!

Comment: Being a bit stubborn here myself... why don't you want to reindex? A FH re-index is an operation that is done _very_ often in Fredhopper servers, and it really doesn't take that long to do...

Comment: But wouldn't that mean re-feeding 6000 Xml files back through FH's incoming folder - in the correct order!

Comment: It would mean putting the files back, sure, but the files are already ordered correctly (naming convention). So no, it's not really a big deal.

Comment: Im sure Ive had problems in the past with contention between Windows moving each file and the XmlLoader picking them up when you just drag and drop this number of files though.

Comment: Also, a wipe indices and reindex will affect our website - all the content will disappear temporarily!

Comment: That's also why Fredhopper PS (and Tridion PS) recommends to have at least 2 FH servers. While re-indexing the server is not available for querying.

Comment: A complete FAS server installation (Query and Index) on two separate servers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned on the documentation page you linked, your attribute needs to be live for you to use it as a facet, sort by it, or filter by it. The example you gave would be a facet.

So yes, you'll need to make it live and re-index. While you're at it, you should think about other attributes that you might want to use for these things in the future :)